# Proving inequality using calculus

Tags: calculus

Hi I'm trying to prove a rather simple inequality using calculus but I cant seem to find a way to do it =/

I know how to prove this inequality using function investigate but when I try to do it in the calculus way Im getting lost.

Lets take a rather simple inequality like:
$$a^2 + ab + b^2 > 0$$
$$b \neq 0$$
$a,b \in \mathbb R$

It's easy to see that this is true $a = 1 > 0, \sqrt{b^2 - 4b^2} < 0$
But how can i do it just by using calculus?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do we know about $a,b$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner oh yes i forgot that b =/ 0 (this is why i could say that there is no sqrt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $a^2+2a\frac{b}{2}+b^2/4+b^2-b^2/4=(a+b/2)^2+\frac{3}{4}b^2>0$ since $b\ne 0$

Comment: Oh wow i would have never think about it i tried to do a^2 + 2ab + b^2 - ab which didnt lead me to something useful